# How do I modify the bound value for a field in a bound form in django?

Tags: django

I override the `__init__` method of my Form.
I can set the initial value by doing the following:

```
self.fields['fieldname'].initial = ....
```

But given that it is bound, calling the above has no effect.
I tried doing this:

```
self.fields['fieldname'].bound_data = ....
```

but this does not work.
Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Why do you want to modify the bound data?

Comment: In the bigger picture, I am using formwizard. If the previous form's selection has changed; I want to prefill the next form with new data.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can update the form's `data` dict

```
self.data['fieldname'] = new_value
```

`bound_data` is a method, not an attribute, so you can't set the value there.

`request.GET` and `request.POST` are immutable, unless you create a `copy()`. You could do the copy in your `__init__` method, or before you bind the form.

```
data = request.POST.copy()
form = MyForm(data=data)
```

Comment: I tried this and it threw the error: `This QueryDict instance is immutable`

Comment: You need to copy the `QueryDict` then change that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Looks like `self.data` is immutable too. Making a copy of `request.POST` as you suggested does the trick though.

Comment: @mgalgs `self.data` is the data you construct the form with. It will only be immutable if you use an immutable object like `request.POST`.

Comment: Ah OK. Thanks for the explanation.